# Как удалить групповой чат в Telegram используя Telegram API

Tags: android, telegram, xamarin-studio

Я знаю, как удалять каналы в Telegram используя API, но мне непонятно, какие функции я должен использовать для удаления чата.

Comment: И как же удаляются каналы? Это подходит? https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteHistory

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43686833

Comment: @mymedia, каналы удаляются просто. Функция с id = -1072619549, channels.deleteChannel. А, вот, для чатов такой однозначной функции не нашел. То есть, Вы считаете, что если из чата удалить все сообщение, то он самоуничтожится? Как-то маловероятно... Но я попробую, спасибо

Comment: По идее, если речь о суппергруппах, то это почти что то же самое, что и каналы. Передав id такой группы в этот метод, она наверняка удалится. С обычными группами дела обстоят чуть по-другому: из-за того, что один участник удалит у себя такой чат, у других ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @mymedia, ладно, пока вопрос не особо актуален, а дальше видно будет...